# Need to show the particular user details without showing the value in search box in openerp?

Tags: python, odoo

I want to show the particular user details without showing the value in search box. Here is the images,

[image]

**And Search View XML:**

```
<record id="view_attendance_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Attendance</field>
        <field name="model">hr.employee.attendance</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Attendance">
                <field name="hr_employee_id" string="Employee"/>

            </search>
         </field>
     </record>

   <record id="hr_employee_attendance_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Employee Attendance</field>
        <field name="res_model">hr.employee.attendance</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
         <field name="context">{'search_default_hr_employee_id':1}</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="hr_employee_attendance_tree_view"/>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_attendance_filter"/>
    </record>
```

Here from above xml code I am sending `search_default_hr_employee_id`, So it is showing the user name in search box. But I want the particular user list without showing the user name in search box.

Comment: So client don't want that . and u frwded image to stackoverflow so that they will solve it for u . :D  Anyway if u don't want search box then remove it from xml .

Comment: @PriyankPatel Thanks for reply. I need search box, But user name need not show in the search box. If you have any idea please give the solution.

Comment: Paste view xml of employee search module here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
<record id="view_attendance_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Attendance</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee.attendance</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Attendance">
            <field name="hr_employee_id" string=" "/>
        </search>
     </field>
 </record>

<record id="hr_employee_attendance_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Employee Attendance</field>
    <field name="res_model">hr.employee.attendance</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
     <field name="context">{'search_default_hr_employee_id':1}</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="hr_employee_attendance_tree_view"/>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_attendance_filter"/>
</record>
```

If you give field **string="Employee"** to **hr_employee_id** than it will display Employee as your problem. But give empty string than it will works. If you remove string than it will show **Employee** ahead.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: If the string is null, then openerp will select the field name specified in the python, if that also null, then field name will be sowed as 'unknown'. So here please edit the answer and specify string=" "

Comment: @Odedra thanks for reply and sorry for late reply. I am expecting remove employee filter, But I need employee filter hiding way.

Comment: I think this answer through solve your problem. This answer will hide the Employee name, and works as a Employee Filter. When you write name in search view, the employee name will be search as you required, Thanks.

Comment: @codeimplementer: if you want to search hiding a way that you can do one thing. Add select=1 to your .py side or view side where employee filter field is define.

Answer (score 0):

Paste in your in xml in new module:

```
<record id="view_attendance_filter_yourcompany" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Attendance</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="parent_module_name.view_attendance_filter"/>
    <field name="model">hr.employee.attendance</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <field name="hr_employee_id" position="replace"/>
     </field>
 </record>
```

Do not forget to update **openerp**.py file.